# How can I remove hard water build up from a washing machine?

Tags: water, washing-machine

What is the best way to remove any sediment build up from having hard water from a washing machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much anything acidic will do the trick.  There is an [overview of citric acid-based products you can purchase, and home remedies such as lemon juice and vinegar](http://www.dishwasherhardwater.com/).  Here are [more details on using vinegar](http://www.ehow.com/how_4856127_clean-water-deposits-washing-machine.html).

Answer (score 2):

There's a product called CLR (Calcium,Lime, Rust) that you can pour on a sponge and scrub down the drum.  Use gloves!  It probably wouldn't hurt to pour the rest of the bottle in and run a small load (no clothes) to clean out the piping as well.